# Using getattr() to access built-in functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword, built-in, getattr

I would like to use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#getattr) to access Python's built-in functions. Is that possible?

For example:

```
getattr(???, 'abs')
```

I know I can just simply do:

```
>>> abs
<built-in function abs>
```

But I want to use `getattr`, because the keyword names are strings.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### The `builtins` module:

You could try importing `builtins` module:

```
>>> import builtins
>>> getattr(builtins, 'abs')
<built-in function abs>
>>>
```

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html):

> This module provides direct access to all ‘built-in’ identifiers of Python; for example, `builtins.open` is the full name for the built-in function `open()`. See Built-in Functions and Built-in Constants for documentation.

So the above mentions that `builtins.open` is the `open` function. So `abs` is the same `builtins.abs` is the same thing as `abs`. But for `gettatr`, `getattr(builtins, 'abs')` is also the same as `builtins.abs`.

### The original `__bultins__` (NOT RECOMMENDED):

You could try getting from the `__builtins__`:

```
>>> getattr(__builtins__, 'abs')
<built-in function abs>
>>>
```

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html?highlight=__builtins__#builtins-and-restricted-execution):

> **CPython implementation detail:** Users should not touch `__builtins__`; it
> is strictly an implementation detail. Users wanting to override values
> in the `builtins` namespace should `import` the `builtins` module and modify
> its attributes appropriately.
>
> The `builtins` namespace associated with the execution of a code block
> is actually found by looking up the name `__builtins__` in its global
> namespace; this should be a dictionary or a module (in the latter case
> the module’s dictionary is used). By default, when in the **main**
> module, `__builtins__` is the built-in module `builtins`; when in any
> other module, `__builtins__` is an alias for the dictionary of the
> `builtins` module itself.

As you can see, it's not recommended, also usually the `__builtins__` is a `dict`, rather than a module.

If you write your code in modules, `__builtins__` would return dictionary aliases of the `builtins` module, which would give something like: `{..., 'abs': <built-in function abs>, ...}`.

## More on `getattr`:

Just to have more idea about `getattr`, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

> Return the value of the named attribute of *object*. name must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. For example, `getattr(x, 'foobar')` is equivalent to `x.foobar`. If the named attribute does not exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise `AttributeError` is raised.

So:

```
>>> import builtins
>>> getattr(builtins, 'abs')
<built-in function abs>
>>>
```

Is the same as:

```
>>> import builtins
>>> builtins.abs
<built-in function abs>
>>>
```

So you might be wondering since:

```
>>> abs
<built-in function abs>
```

Gives the same thing, why we can't just do:

```
getattr(abs)
```

The reason we can't do that is that that `getattr` is suppose to be calling methods/functions/classes *of* a classes/modules.

The reason using `getattr(builtins, 'abs')` works is because `builtins` is a module and `abs` is a class/method, it stores all the built-in Python keywords as methods in that module.

All the keywords are showed on this [page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions) of the documentation.